# Windows Workflow Foundation 4.0 and Tracking

Tags: windows, workflow-foundation, tracking

I'm working with the Beta 2 version of Visual Studio 2010 to get some advanced learning using WF4.  I've been working with the SqlTracking Sample in the WF_WCF_Samples SDK, and have gotten a pretty good understanding of how to emit and store tracking data in a SQL Database, but haven't seen anything on how to query the data when needed.  Does anyone know if there are any .Net classes that are to be used for querying the tracking data, and if so are there any known samples, tutorials, or articles that describe how to query the tracking data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Matt Winkler, from the Microsoft WF4 Team, there isn't any built in API for querying the tracking data, the developer must write his/her own.

Answer (score 0):

These can help:

- [WorkflowInstanceQuery Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.tracking.workflowinstancequery%28VS.100%29.aspx)
- [Workflow Tracking and Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513992%28VS.100%29.aspx)
- [Tracking Participants in .NET 4 Beta 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/endpoint/archive/2009/07/14/tracking-participants-in-net-4-beta-1.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the post, but I guess I'm confused.  It looks to me that the links above are all samples of how to emit the tracking data and then store it somewhere (like a database or the event log).  I'm looking for a mechanism to query the data after it has been stored.  In .Net 3.5 we used the the SqlTrackingQuery and it's TryGetWorkflow() method to do this.  That is the sort of thing I'm trying to find -- a mechanism to query the stored data.  Maybe that isn't included in WF4, and I might have to write my own queries.

Comment: It may be, I can't figure it out for sure because of the limited amount of documentation, but at the very least, that class is used in the tracking profile to emit tracking records, which can then be used by the TrackingParticipant to store them somewhere.  It may, or may not be used also to query the tracking records once they are stored -- like I said, it's hard to tell because of the lack of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, but there is actually a more or less official API in AppFabric: [Windows Server AppFabric Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh475804.aspx)

You'll have to find the actual DLL's in %SystemRoot%\AppFabric (after installing AppFabric, of course). Pretty weird place to put it.

The key classes to look are at are SqlInstanceQueryProvider, InstanceQueryExecuteArgs. The query API is asynchronous and can be used something like this (C#):

```
public InstanceInfo GetWorkflowInstanceInformation(Guid workflowInstanceId, string connectionString)
{
    var instanceQueryProvider = new SqlInstanceQueryProvider();

    // Connection string to the instance store needs to be set like this:
    var parameters = new NameValueCollection()
    {
        {"connectionString", connectionString}
    };
    instanceQueryProvider.Initialize("Provider", parameters);

    var queryArgs = new InstanceQueryExecuteArgs()
    {
        InstanceId = new List<Guid>() { workflowInstanceId }
    };

    // Total ruin the asynchronous advantages and use a Mutex to lock on.
    var waitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    IEnumerable<InstanceInfo> retrievedInstanceInfos = null;
    var query = instanceQueryProvider.CreateInstanceQuery();
    query.BeginExecuteQuery(
        queryArgs,
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
        ar =>
        {
            lock (synchronizer)
            {
                retrievedInstanceInfos = query.EndExecuteQuery(ar).ToList();
            }
            waitEvent.Set();
        },
        null);

    var waitResult = waitEvent.WaitOne(5000);
    if (waitResult)
    {
        List<InstanceInfo> instances = null;
        lock (synchronizer)
        {
            if (retrievedInstanceInfos != null)
            {
                instances = retrievedInstanceInfos.ToList();
            }
        }

        if (instances != null)
        {
            if (instances.Count() == 1)
            {
                return instances.Single();
            }

            if (!instances.Any())
            {
                Log.Warning("Request for non-existing WorkflowInstanceInfo: {0}.", workflowInstanceId);
                return null;
            }

            Log.Error("More than one(!) WorkflowInstanceInfo for id: {0}.", workflowInstanceId);
        }
    }

    Log.Error("Time out retrieving information for id: {0}.", workflowInstanceId);
    return null;
}
```

And just to clarify - this does NOT give you access to the tracking data, which are stored in the Monitoring Database. This API is only for the Persistence Database.